# How to add a cron job to run php script

Tags: linux, cron

I have a php script I'm trying to run using a cron job. I can execute the script from CLI doing

```
/usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php
```

So I have tried..

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php
```

and

```
crontab 0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php
```

and

```
crontab -e 0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php
```

[Vince V. says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220346/550309) to open your cronfile and do it.. When I enter `crontab -e`, I get

```
*/5 * * * * /root/autosvnup.sh
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
"/tmp/crontab.ZBGTFu" 1L, 31C
```

Then I get stuck and not sure what to do.. Would someone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the `vi` editor, your default text editor (check `man vi`). Here are the commands to edit your crontab with `vi`:

> 1. `Ctrl-c` your `/usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php`.
> 2. Move the cursor to the first empty line
> 3. Press `i` into the `vi` console
> 4. Paste using your mouse.
> 5. Hit `ESC`.
> 6. Write `:wq`.
> 7. Hit `RETURN`.

Comment: Not sure how to get the cursor on the first empty line. I can only move it left and right on the first line (*/5 * * ...). Gonna look up the vi manual

Comment: This will get you going [Basic vi Commands](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html)

Comment: note that first you should to put the time you want it to run `* * * * *` = every minute. When you are done your line should look something like this `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php`. To write into `vi` press `i`, when done go to `step 5`

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the vim text editor. When you do `crontab -e` it opens up your crontab in the default editor. The default editor can be changed by, for example:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

..some find nano a lot easier to work with as vim has a somewhat steep learning curve.

To add your script to the crontab, just insert it on a new line, so that your crontab looks like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /root/autosvnup.sh
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php Import_Product_Data.php
```

Then save+exit, and it should run once every midnight (as per the `0 0 * * *`)

Comment: Not sure how to get the cursor on a new line. I can only move it left and right on the first line (*/5 * * ...)

Comment: @Shredder That'd be beyond the scope of this answer. I recommend checking out this link: http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html

Comment: this should be marked as the answer really, not sure why it doesn't have more upvotes either.