# How to automatically update today's DATE in a DATE field of mysql at the start of next day?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a requirement in which a date field n my table should be updated automatically at the start of next day(12:00 am).

Comment: you will need cron jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use

- a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to run an `UPDATE` statement through the mysql command line interface

```
    /path/to/mysql -u<user> -p"<password>" <db_name> -e "UPDATE table_name SET n = CURDATE()"
```

- or a [MySQL event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html), e.g.

```sql
CREATE EVENT update_date_column 
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE()
  DO UPDATE table_name SET n = CURDATE();
```

If you'll go with event approach:

- use [`SHOW EVENTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-events.html) to list created events with their attributes (e.g. `status`)
- use [`SHOW PROCESSLIST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html) to check if the event scheduler is enabled. If it's ON you should see a process "`Daemon`" by user "`event_scheduler`".
- use `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`to enable the scheduler if it's currently not enabled.
- More on configuring event scheduler read [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

---

*But the question is why do you need to do this? It smells like a bad design.*

Comment: Actually i working with a CMS project in which dynamic things should happen tats why,,tnks 4 ur reply by the way i read about this event but where should i need to save this i mean as a procedure or smetng else.

Comment: You just execute `CREATE EVENT` statement as any other DDL statement (e.g. `CREATE TABLE`) and the information about this event is stored in a special table in MySQL. You see all events with their attributes by issuing `SHOW EVENTS`.

Comment: ok sir ill go by this method tnk u very much 4 answering

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be writing a cron to run at midnight and do that thing for you.

```
00 00 * * * path/to/your/script
```

Comment: tnks 4 ur reply ill try that :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for corn jobs have a look at this question

[How to add a cron job to run php script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13845021/829533)

You need to create a PHP file say `change.php` and write the code to make changes to your mysql database's tables, and add the following lines to the corn

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/php change.php
```

Comment: tnks 4 ur reply ill try that :)